# Handling button presses with a FEZHAT shield for Rasperry Pi in UWP app

Tags: uwp

I have a timer that reads sensor values in my UWP app and it also check the button state on the shield. Unfortunately not all button presses are handled as expected. It's a bit of hit and miss. What would be a good approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button clicks on the FEZHAT should be polled at a high frequency.

I would suggest putting to DispatcherTimers in your code. One to handle the button presses (I use 50ms intervals) and the other one for handling the sensor readings (f.e. 5000MS).